# Loops for removing unnecessary lines

Tags: c#, casting

I have the following method:

```
private void removeUnnecessaryLines(List<ScatterViewItem> list)
{
    List<Line> remove = new List<Line>();
    foreach (Line line in lines)
    {
        SourceFile destination = (line.Tag as Call).getCallee();

        foreach (ScatterViewItem svi in list)
        {
            SourceFile test = svi.Tag as SourceFile;
            if (test.Equals(destination))
            {
                remove.Add(line);
            }
        }
    }

    foreach (Line l in remove)
    {
        lines.Remove(l);
        Dependencies.Children.Remove(l);
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is a lot of iteration and casting. Is there a simple way to improve that?

Comment: This looks like C# (though you should mention that in the tags). Can you use LINQ?

Comment: @sepp2k yes it is c# and i could use linq

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The most obvious improvement would be to use LINQ's `Where` method to filter the `lines` list instead of building up a list of to-be-deleted items and then deleting them. In addition to being easier to read and understand it will have the benefit of its runtime not being quadratic in the length of `lines`.

You can also use the `List<T>.RemoveAll` method which also takes a predicate like `Where` (though the predicate specifies the items to be removed, so it's in a way the opposite of `Where`), but modifies the list in-place, like your solution did.

Comment: Would that work if returning a new list was not an option?

Comment: @Sean: It would if reassigning `lines` is an option (i.e. you could reassign lines to the result of Where + ToList). If that is also not an option, then no, I'm afraid it won't work for you. Though I'd have to ask why it isn't an option. I'd suspect that any such restriction would be the result of a design flaw (though of course I would not presume to say for sure without knowing the design).

Comment: Your right, it generally would be the result of a design flaw. Unfortunately with third party controls it might not be my design. But assuming that reassigning lines is a possibility it is definitely the best option.

Answer (score 1):

1. I would not insist on replacing `lines.Remove` with `lines = lines.Where(...)`. I believe this replacement is subjective since you will still need to remove the same lines from `Dependencies.Children` collection. Instead I would modify `foreach` statement.
2. If you do not checking `test == null` then instead of `test = svi.Tag as SourceFile`, I would use `test = (SourceFile)svi.Tag`. Resharper says the same.
3. Second nested `foreach` is definitely a `Contains` statement
4. Rename `remove` -> `linesToRemove` since `remove` is not a noun
5. `IEnumerable<>` for method parameter, not `List<>`
6. Better name for `list` parameter? It doesn't clear what is that parameter used for from method signature
7. Why not `UpperCamelCase`?

Result:

```
private static void RemoveUnnecessaryLines(IEnumerable<ScatterViewItem> list)
{
    var linesToRemove = lines
        .Select(line => ((Call)line.Tag).getCallee())
        .Where(destination => list.Any(svi => Equals(svi.Tag, destination)))
        .ToList();

    foreach (Line l in linesToRemove)
    {
        lines.Remove(l);
        Dependencies.Children.Remove(l);
    }
}
```